# jQuery with multi datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I have dynamic form, Now when Input generated, there is 2 datepicker (FromDate, ToDate), and you can generate many of this tow inputs.

The Input come like this:

```
<input type="text" class="input-date displayDate complexField" name="Course[FromDate][1]" value="" />

<input type="text" class="input-date displayDate complexField" name="Course[ToDate][1]" value="" />
```

Each Input will generate jQuery for datepicker like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    {/literal}$(".input-date").datepicker({literal}{ 
        dateFormat: dFormat,
        showOn: 'button',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date(1940, 1 - 1, 1),
        maxDate: '+10y',
        yearRange: '-99:+99',
        onSelect: function(selected) {
                    $("[name^='Course[FromDate]']").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)});
                    $("[name^='Course[ToDate]']").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)});
                }

    });
```

Now everything work fine, you can add many these two inputs and all of them with datepicker.

**The Only problem is:**

The option **onSelect** work fine only if you have only the first element (FromDate and ToDate) the ToDate can't be greater than FromDate and vice versa,

**But** when I add other elemnts which will be:

```
<input type="text" class="input-date displayDate complexField" name="Course[FromDate][2]" value="" />

<input type="text" class="input-date displayDate complexField" name="Course[ToDate][2]" value="" />
```

The **onSelect** will work wrong, it will work 4 together, I need it work with elements with array index (1) alone, and in elements with index number (2) works alone and so on.

Please advice me on this ...

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code and try agin**

```
  $('document').ready(function(){
   $('.input-date').on('click',function(){
   $(this).datepicker({literal}{ 
        dateFormat: dFormat,
        showOn: 'button',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date(1940, 1 - 1, 1),
        maxDate: '+10y',
        yearRange: '-99:+99',
        onSelect: function(selected) {
                    $("[name^='Course[FromDate]']").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)});
                    $("[name^='Course[ToDate]']").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)});
                }
});
});
```

Comment: The (datepicker) not work with input anymore after this change !